# JS spliting a string that contains numbers returns array with empty element

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Given a string for example `foo123` and splitting it so that integers and characters are separated using `split(/(\d+)/g)` returns an array with empty element at the end

```js
let str  = 'foo123'
let splits = str.split(/(\d+)/g)
console.log(splits)
```

Output:

```
[ 'foo', '123', '']
```

while I am expecting `[ 'foo', '123']`, why does this happen and how can I split characters from integers without empty element at the end? Also when the input string is e.g `foo123bar` split method doesn't return empty element.

Answer (score 3):

> why does this happen

You are using a sequence of digits as *delimiter*. The delimiter separates the left side from the right side. In your example the delimiter is *at the end* of the string, so the right side is empty (-> empty string).

> Why split method doesn't return empty element when the input string is e.g foo123bar ?

Because the string doesn't *end* with your delimiter.

This is no different than using any other value as delimiter

```js
console.log('foo,'.split(','));
console.log('foo,bar'.split(','));
```

What's special about using a regular expression is that the delimiter itself is included in the output if it's part of a capture group.

---

If the input is always of the the same structure, i.e. letters followed by digits, I would just find the index of the first digit and then slice the string accordingly:

```js
function split(str) {
  const match  = str.match(/\d/);
  if (match) {
    return [str.slice(0, match.index), str.slice(match.index)];
  }
  return [str];
}

console.log(split('foo123'));
```

Comment: for well detailed answer +1.  on side note:- Why slice why not `str.match(/[A-Z]+|\d+/gi)` ?

Comment: It's just another way `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`. Any regular expression really depends on the range of possible inputs. We only know about one, so I tried to make as few assumptions as possible (but granted, expecting the input to always be non-digits followed by digits is a big assumption).

Comment: one question why `'foo123'.split(/\d+/)` and `'foo123'.split(/(\d+/))`  gives different results ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I kind of mentioned this in my answer: if the delimiter contains a capture group, the contents of the capture group is included in the output. Hence if there is no capture group, no part of the delimiter is included.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let str  = 'foo123'
let splits = str.split(/(\d+)/g).filter(x => x!="")
console.log(splits)
```

This is happening becouse `split` method split your array (string in this case) to the left and right... to avoid this just ose filter to remove blank spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
let str  = 'foo123'
let splits = str.split(/(\d+)/g).filter(Boolean)
console.log(splits)
```

It adds an empty element because you are using a sequence of digits as a delimiter. So right side will be empty in your case because there is no character after digits.

Comment: How is that different from Daniel's answer?

Comment: not a big difference, But inside the filter, you can simply write Boolean instated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for slice definition:
....
If the original text starts or ends with a separator, the function returns an array whose first or last element will be the empty text, respectively.
...